# what does numpy.apply_along_axis perform exactly?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have come across the [numpy.apply_along_axis](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) function in some code. And I don't understand the documentation about it.

This is an example of the documentation:

```
>>> def new_func(a):
...     """Divide elements of a by 2."""
...     return a * 0.5
>>> b = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
>>> np.apply_along_axis(new_func, 0, b)
array([[ 0.5,  1. ,  1.5],
       [ 2. ,  2.5,  3. ],
       [ 3.5,  4. ,  4.5]])
```

As far I as thought I understood the documentation, I would have expected:

```
array([[ 0.5,  1. ,  1.5],
       [ 4  ,  5  ,  6  ],
       [ 7  ,  8  ,  9  ]])
```

i.e.  having applied the function along the axis **[1,2,3]** which is axis **0** in [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]

Obviously I am wrong. Could you correct me ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`apply_along_axis` applies the supplied function along 1D slices of the input array, with the slices taken along the axis you specify. So in your example, `new_func` is applied over each slice of the array along the first axis. It becomes clearer if you use a vector valued function, rather than a scalar, like this:

```
In [20]: b = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])

In [21]: np.apply_along_axis(np.diff,0,b)
Out[21]: 
array([[3, 3, 3],
       [3, 3, 3]])

In [22]: np.apply_along_axis(np.diff,1,b)
Out[22]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1]])
```

Here, `numpy.diff` (i.e. the arithmetic difference of adjacent array elements) is applied along each slice of either the first or second axis (dimension) of the input array.

Comment: Not knowing what np.diff does, I did not get this explanation. I assume np.diff returns the number of different items when comparing two array items?

Comment: @Simeon: You don't need to assume. You can read exactly what the function does: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html?highlight=diff#numpy.diff

Comment: To be more on point I suggest altering your explanation to use a more intuitive function here. Reading about functionality of a special function while trying to understand another explanation sometimes is distracting.

Answer (score 5):

The function is performed on 1-d arrays along axis=0. You can specify another axis using the "axis" argument. A usage of this paradigm is:

```
np.apply_along_axis(np.cumsum, 0, b)
```

The function was performed on each subarray along dimension 0. So, it is meant for 1-D functions and returns a 1D array for each 1-D input.

Another example is :

```
np.apply_along_axis(np.sum, 0, b)
```

Provides a scalar output for a 1-D array.
Of course you could just set the axis parameter in cumsum or sum to do the above, but the point here is that it can be used for any 1-D function you write.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake come from two misconceptions of what axis 0 truly is and also what apply_along_axis should be used for:

Misconception 1:

In your array, axis 0 is **not** [1,2,3] which will be found with b[0,:] and would represent the first slice from axis 1. The first slice from axis 0 is found with indexing **b[:,0]** which would return [1,4,7]. And the 3 slices or vector from axis 0 you will perform calculation on by are:

```
>>> b = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
>>> b[:,0]
array([1, 4, 7])
>>> b[:,1]
array([2, 5, 8])
>>> b[:,2]
array([3, 6, 9])
```

Misconception 2:

The function you want to apply is actually element wise. You won't see any difference while changing the axis since the operation doesn't apply to the axis but to every element independently and won't affect the array shape:

```
>>> b*0.5
array([[0.5, 1. , 1.5],
       [2. , 2.5, 3. ],
       [3.5, 4. , 4.5]])
```

Now, let's dive a bit more and square the matrix in order add more variation between each element and perform the np.diff as showed from another answer in this field:

```
>>> b**=2
>>> b
array([[ 1,  4,  9],
       [16, 25, 36],
       [49, 64, 81]])
```

Let's take every slice of axis 0 And apply np.diff to each of them:

```
>>> b[:,0]
array([ 1, 16, 49])
>>> np.diff(b[:,0])
array([15, 33])

>>> b[:,1]
array([ 4, 25, 64])
>>> np.diff(b[:,1])
array([21, 39])

>>> b[:,2]
array([ 9, 36, 81])
>>> np.diff(b[:,2])
array([27, 45])
```

For recall, the np.diff function is equivalent to:

```
>>> b[1::,0]-b[0:-1,0]
array([15, 33])
```

This function return the difference between X[i+1]-X[i] with i=[0,len(X)-1] with X a vector

Hence the result of the **function np.diff apply along axis 0**:

```
>>> np.apply_along_axis(np.diff, 0, b)
array([[15, 21, 27],
       [33, 39, 45]])
```

Finally you might have expected this answer instead of the one just above:

```
array([[15, 33],
       [21, 39],
       [27, 45]])
```

Then get back to the original array and understand that the function np.diff is applied to axis 0 hence vertically from a numpy view point

Answer (score 0):

```
""" simple examples to help understand numpy apply_along_axis """

import numpy as np

Start with 2d, an array of 3 rows x 10 columns --

A = np.arange( 3 * 10 ).reshape( 3, 10 )
^   <----- axis 1 horizontal ---->
|  [[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9]
|   [10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
|   [20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29]]
V axis 0 vertical

np.apply_along_axis( print, axis=0, arr=A )
    # calls `print` 10 times, with each vertical column

np.apply_along_axis( print, axis=1, arr=A )
    # calls `print` 3 times, with each horizontal row
```

If you have several axis, it's useful to give them names, like

```
    Lat, Lon, Height = 0, 1, 2
    ... axis=Lat ...
```

---

It's confusing that `avheight = A.mean( axis=Height )` **drops** the Height axis,
leaving e.g. a 2d array of shape (nr Lat, nr Lon).

Next, a 3d example:

```
A = np.arange( 2 * 3 * 5 ).reshape( 2, 3, 5 )
print( "A: %s \n%s \n" % ( A.shape, A ))

    # print the 1d lines (rows, columns, zlines) along each axis --
for axis in [0, 1, 2]:
    print( f"\n-- np.apply_along_axis( print, {axis}, A )" )
    np.apply_along_axis( print, axis, A )

print( "\n# stack the 1d lines in order -> A again --" )
for axis in [0, 1, 2]:
    id = lambda x: x
    lines = [np.apply_along_axis( id, axis, A )]  # 1d, row / col / zline
    stack = np.stack( lines, axis=-1 ).squeeze()  # squeeze (2, 3, 5, 1) -> (2, 3, 5)
    print( "stack == A:", np.all( stack == A ))
```